# build/install/<project>-shadow directory -- what is it?

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, uberjar, shadowjar

What is `build/install/gradleHelloWorld-shadow`?  What should or shouldn't be in that directory?

simplest possible "hello world" fails to build:

```
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/gradleHelloWorld$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/gradleHelloWorld$ gradle clean runShadow

> Task :shadowJar 
A problem was found with the configuration of task ':shadowJar'. Registering invalid inputs and outputs via TaskInputs and TaskOutputs methods has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0.
 - No value has been specified for property 'mainClassName'.
The SimpleWorkResult type has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use WorkResults.didWork() instead.

> Task :startShadowScripts 
Using TaskInputs.file() with something that doesn't resolve to a File object has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Use TaskInputs.files() instead.


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':installShadowDist'.
> The specified installation directory '/home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/gradleHelloWorld/build/install/gradleHelloWorld-shadow' is neither empty nor does it contain an installation for 'gradleHelloWorld'.
  If you really want to install to this directory, delete it and run the install task again.
  Alternatively, choose a different installation directory.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
5 actionable tasks: 5 executed

Publishing build scan...
https://gradle.com/s/t7jbmhjz23giw

thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/gradleHelloWorld$
```

build file:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.gradle.build-scan' version '1.8' 
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
    id 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow' version '2.0.1'
}

buildScan {
    licenseAgreementUrl = 'https://gradle.com/terms-of-service'
    licenseAgree = 'yes'
    publishAlways()
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

mainClassName = 'net.bounceme.dur.gradle.hello.App'

shadowJar {
    baseName = 'greeter'
    classifier = null
    version = null
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

configurations {
    provided
}

dependencies {
}
```

project after aborted `runShadow`:

```
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/gradleHelloWorld$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/gradleHelloWorld$ tree
.
├── build
│   ├── classes
│   │   └── java
│   │       └── main
│   │           └── net
│   │               └── bounceme
│   │                   └── dur
│   │                       └── gradle
│   │                           └── hello
│   │                               └── App.class
│   ├── install
│   │   └── gradleHelloWorld-shadow
│   ├── libs
│   │   └── greeter.jar
│   ├── scriptsShadow
│   │   ├── gradleHelloWorld
│   │   └── gradleHelloWorld.bat
│   └── tmp
│       ├── compileJava
│       └── shadowJar
│           └── MANIFEST.MF
├── build.gradle
├── gradle
│   └── wrapper
│       ├── gradle-wrapper.jar
│       └── gradle-wrapper.properties
├── gradlew
├── gradlew.bat
├── settings.gradle
└── src
    ├── main
    │   └── java
    │       ├── dur
    │       └── net
    │           └── bounceme
    │               └── dur
    │                   └── gradle
    │                       └── hello
    │                           └── App.java
    └── test
        └── java

29 directories, 12 files
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/gradleHelloWorld$
```

the `/home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/gradleHelloWorld/build/install/gradleHelloWorld-shadow` directory at issue is removed by clean, establishing that gradle is building this directory.

Just upgraded gradle:

```
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ sdk ls gradle
==== INTERNET NOT REACHABLE! ===================================================

 Some functionality is disabled or only partially available.
 If this persists, please enable the offline mode:

   $ sdk offline

================================================================================

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Offline: only showing installed gradle versions
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 > 4.3.1
 * 4.2.1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
* - installed                                                                   
> - currently in use                                                            
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
thufir@dur:~$
```

(The wi-fi can be a bit flaky.)

Comment: `No value has been specified for property 'mainClassName'.` Specify a main-class and just do a clean build.

Comment: @LazerBanana see below work-around.  Also, the `mainClassName` property was specified in the build file -- presumably that error relates to the `shadowJar` plugin itself.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is **unclear to me**, as far as I can see error msg is quite clear what is wrong.

Not sure what is the workaround you posted as well, I said in the comment to run clean, because presumably, that's what the plugin demands, just check the source code of the plugin if interested why.

Anyway.

> The Shadow plugin will also configure distribution tasks when in the presence of the application plugin. The plugin will create shadowDistZip and shadowDistTar which creates Zip and Tar distributions respectively. Each distribution will contain the shadowed JAR file along with the necessary start scripts to launch the application.

Additionally, the plugin will create the installShadowDist and startShadowScripts tasks which stages the necessary files for a distribution to build/install/-shadow/.

Another thing is that mainClassName

> Just like the normal jar task, when the application plugin is applied, the shadowJar manifest will be configured to contain the Main-Class attribute with the value specified in the project’s mainClassName attribute.

`runShadow` is a javaExec task probably needs configuring?

```
runShadow {
  // classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath

  main = 'net.bounceme.dur.gradle.hello.App'

  // arguments to pass to the application
  // args 'appArg1'
}
```

> When applied along with the application plugin, the runShadow task will be created for starting the application from the shadowed JAR. The runShadow task is a JavaExec task that is configured to execute java -jar myproject-all.jar. It can be configured the same as any other JavaExec task.

[ShadowJar Documentation](http://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/)

Comment: please take another look at the build file.  consider, please, that the error about setting the main class does not relate to the build file.  Take a look at the other errors for context.  Also, note that the main class entry point is set when the JAR is built with `shadowJar` or `assembleShadowDist`.  because why?  because it's configured in gradle.build....

Comment: to demonstrate that `shadowJar` builds a JAR correctly:  https://gist.github.com/THUFIR/ed567bb3681370e7eeddacd04e544d88   but, then, why doesn't `runShadow` work?

Comment: Yeah, I see the `build.gradle`, I think you misunderstood my intentions, RunShadow is a JavaExec task and you need to put mainClass in agrs, I think.

Comment: what's your gradle version?  I think it's a bug -- see new answer from me.

Answer (score 0):

work-around:

```
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/gradleHelloWorld$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/gradleHelloWorld$ gradle clean assembleShadowDist

> Task :shadowJar 
A problem was found with the configuration of task ':shadowJar'. Registering invalid inputs and outputs via TaskInputs and TaskOutputs methods has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0.
 - No value has been specified for property 'mainClassName'.
The SimpleWorkResult type has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use WorkResults.didWork() instead.

> Task :startShadowScripts 
Using TaskInputs.file() with something that doesn't resolve to a File object has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Use TaskInputs.files() instead.


BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 0s
6 actionable tasks: 6 executed
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/gradleHelloWorld$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/gradleHelloWorld$ cd build/libs/
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/gradleHelloWorld/build/libs$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/gradleHelloWorld/build/libs$ ll
total 20
drwxr-xr-x 2 thufir thufir 4096 Nov 13 02:53 ./
drwxr-xr-x 7 thufir thufir 4096 Nov 13 02:53 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 thufir thufir 1492 Nov 13 02:53 greeter.jar
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/gradleHelloWorld/build/libs$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/gradleHelloWorld/build/libs$ jar xf greeter.jar 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/gradleHelloWorld/build/libs$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/gradleHelloWorld/build/libs$ ll
total 28
drwxr-xr-x 4 thufir thufir 4096 Nov 13 02:53 ./
drwxr-xr-x 7 thufir thufir 4096 Nov 13 02:53 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 thufir thufir 1492 Nov 13 02:53 greeter.jar
drwxr-xr-x 2 thufir thufir 4096 Nov 13 02:53 META-INF/
drwxr-xr-x 3 thufir thufir 4096 Nov 13 02:53 net/
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/gradleHelloWorld/build/libs$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/gradleHelloWorld/build/libs$ cat META-INF/MANIFEST.MF 
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: net.bounceme.dur.gradle.hello.App

thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/gradleHelloWorld/build/libs$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/gradleHelloWorld/build/libs$ java -jar greeter.jar 
Nov 13, 2017 2:53:38 AM net.bounceme.dur.gradle.hello.App run
INFO: helloooo
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/gradleHelloWorld/build/libs$
```

1. why does this work?
2. why doesn't `runShadow` work?

Answer (score 0):

better solution, still a work-around.  Switching back to gradle 4.2.1 from 4.3.1 works:

```
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/gradleHelloWorld$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/gradleHelloWorld$ sdk use gradle 4.3.1

Using gradle version 4.3.1 in this shell.
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/gradleHelloWorld$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/gradleHelloWorld$ gradle clean runShadow

> Task :shadowJar 
A problem was found with the configuration of task ':shadowJar'. Registering invalid inputs and outputs via TaskInputs and TaskOutputs methods has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0.
 - No value has been specified for property 'mainClassName'.
The SimpleWorkResult type has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use WorkResults.didWork() instead.

> Task :startShadowScripts 
Using TaskInputs.file() with something that doesn't resolve to a File object has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Use TaskInputs.files() instead.


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':installShadowDist'.
> The specified installation directory '/home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/gradleHelloWorld/build/install/gradleHelloWorld-shadow' is neither empty nor does it contain an installation for 'gradleHelloWorld'.
  If you really want to install to this directory, delete it and run the install task again.
  Alternatively, choose a different installation directory.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
5 actionable tasks: 5 executed
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/gradleHelloWorld$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/gradleHelloWorld$ sdk use gradle 4.2.1

Using gradle version 4.2.1 in this shell.
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/gradleHelloWorld$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/gradleHelloWorld$ gradle clean runShadow
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)

> Task :shadowJar
The SimpleWorkResult type has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use WorkResults.didWork() instead.

> Task :runShadow
Nov 13, 2017 12:02:51 PM net.bounceme.dur.gradle.hello.App run
INFO: helloooo


BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 12s
6 actionable tasks: 6 executed
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/gradleHelloWorld$
```

Is this a [bug](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow/issues/339)?

Comment: some runtime API changed maybe ?

Comment: @LazerBanana it's really overy my head.  I think that `shadow` 1.)  isn't declaring a main method, or configuring it properly, and 2.) is expecting this directory to be empty, or not, when it's in the opposite state.  Perhaps it's populated and then deleted during build process?  You're probably more knowledgeable that I, but that's my educated guess...also, it could be in one state during the build but a different state (filled or empty) after the build finishes.  I think you mentioned something about this somewhere...would have to read through again though.

Comment: i have no clue i just tried to help reading the documentation :)